# issues in BroadCast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hai am developing a android Application using broadcast receiver to get latitude and longtitude value.My requirements is always running the broadCast reciver

**My problem**

1.when using broadcast receiver for back ground service is any problem  for long term process.

2.am using wake lock in Broad cast receiver ,is it possible to sleep or Stop the service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My requirements is always running the broadCast reciver

Specifically if you want your broadcastreciever to be on at all times, then you should declare it in the manifest NOT in your code.

1... please clarify

2... if you have a broadcast reciever in your service, and pass a message to it.. this communication would work.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare your broadcast receiver in the manifest file. So it will be available all the time...
And if you want your receiver to work even after the reboot then make another receiver like below to awake your personal broadcast receiver.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent netAvailability = new Intent(context, <YourReceiver>.class);
    netAvailability.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(netAvailability); 
}
```